# What is raw memory in C & C++?

Tags: c++, memory

Sorry for asking this question, but actually I don't know about this.
I have read in the following FAQ entry:
[Can I free() pointers allocated with new? Can I delete pointers allocated with malloc()?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete)

> Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the mechanism used by new and delete to acquire and release raw memory is compatible with `malloc()` and `free()`.

I just want to know that what is this "raw memory"?

Comment: They mean a bucket of bytes.  The storage for an object (different from the object occupying that location, because objects have type).

Comment: *Raw Memory* probably refers to unmanaged memory, in contrast with managed memory (as implemented in Java and C#, for example, including Garbage Collector, etc).

Comment: Why do people always post answers as comments?

Comment: @barakmanos: But in C++, there is no "managed" memory. In this context, "raw" means the unstructured blocks of bytes used as storage for language-level objects.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Where in my comment does it say that there is managed memory in C++???

Comment: @barakmanos: The question is about C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: OK, I was about to say 'what the h##l are you talking about', but I see the logic in what you're saying. The term of *Raw Memory* can refer to unmanaged memory in contrast with managed memory, but it can also refer to "typed" memory vs. "untyped" memory. In the context of the question at hand (in particular, with regards to the comparison between `malloc` and `new`), the answer is probably the "typed/untyped" memory rather than the "managed/unmanaged" memory. This would essentially make your answer below more relevant to this question than the other guy's (R.T.) answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Raw memory" refers to blocks of memory, treated as unstructured arrays of bytes. Higher-level languages use these as the storage for objects; the program usually interacts with these objects, not the low-level byte values.

In C++, raw memory can be allocated dynamically using two different allocation functions:

- `operator new`, used to allocate from the *free store* when you create an object using `new`
- `malloc` from the C library

Memory allocated by `new` must be released with `delete`; and memory allocated with `malloc` must be released with `free`.

The line you quote explains that these might use different mechanisms to manage allocation; so that it's an error to use the wrong function to release memory (e.g. to allocate memory with `new` and try to release it with `free`).

Comment: It's worth noting that the standard refers to raw memory as the _free store_?

Answer (score 7):

Raw memory refers to the unmanaged memory in C and C++. malloc, calloc, realloc, and free are low-level functions that simply deal with raw memory.

You can also refer this Stanford document about [Raw memory](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/19-Assignment-5-Raw-Memory.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In c you used malloc and free to allocate memory.
If malloc rerurned a pointer casted to void, you would have more or less raw memory. The cpp pendant is new and delete. There is also the possibility with special casts to get untyped memory, so called raw memory pointed to by raw pointers. But it is fact that any ressource allocated by new or new[] must be freed by delete resp.delete[]. BUT NOT THE MEMORY ALLOCATED BY REPLACEMENT NEW.