# With std::byte standardized, when do we use a void* and when a byte*?

Tags: c++, byte, c++17, idioms

C++17 will include [`std::byte`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), a type for one atomically-addressable unit of memory, having 8 bits on typical computers.

Before this standardization, there is already a bit of dilemma when pointing into "raw" memory - between using `char*`/`unsigned char*` on one hand or `void *` on the other. Now, one of reasons for prefering `void *` is removed - `std::byte` does not have the same connotations as a `char`; it's about raw memory, not characters.

So, my question is: What is a good rule of thumb, for the days of `std::byte`, regarding when to prefer it over `void *` and when it's the other way around?

---

<sup><sub>Of course when you're dealing with old code, or C code, you're constrained by what it accepts; I mostly mean new code where you get to choose all the types.</sub></sup>

Comment: Huh, I was not aware of `std::byte` – now I will have to retrain myself, as I have been doing `using byte = uint8_t;` in my `types.hh` files for some time now. Good to know.

Comment: `std::byte` is not just raw memory, it is raw memory _with bitwise operations defined for it_.

Comment: @fish2000 you might want to keep doing that -- `std::byte` _is not_ just an `unsigned char` -- not even `a+b` is defined where `a` and `b` are both `std::byte`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(This is a *potential* rule of thumb which comes off the top of my head, not condoned by anyone.)

#### Rule of thumb: When to use which kind of pointer?

- **Use `char *` for sequences of textual characters**, not anything else.
- **Use `void *` in type-erasure scenarios**, i.e. when the pointed-to data is typed, but for some reason a typed pointer must not be used or it cannot be determined whether it's typed or not.
- **Use `byte *` for raw memory** for which there is no indication of it holding any typed data.

An exception to the above:

- Also use `void *`/`unsigned char *`/`char *` when older code;  or when non-C++ code forces you and you would otherwise use `byte *`. But when doing this, you could still wrap such use with a `byte *`-based interface,  thus not exposing this state of affairs to the rest of your C++ code.

#### Examples

`void * my_custom_malloc(size_t size)` - **wrong**
`byte * my_custom_malloc(size_t size)` - **right**

`struct buffer_t { byte* data; size_t length; my_type_t data_type; }` - **wrong**

`struct buffer_t { void* data; size_t length; my_type_t data_type; }` - **right**

Comment: You should use `byte*` over `void*` when the data needs bitwise operations defined for it. Use `char*` when it is character data or (really small) signed integers that you want the basic math operations defined for, and use `unsigned char*` when the data is unsigned (really small) integers that you want the basic math operations defined for

Comment: Old C APIs (and plenty of C++ ones too) tend to use `unsigned char*` for raw memory, not `char*` like you said - that's usually reserved for actual textual characters. Note that `unsigned char` is a separate type to `char` even when `char` is unsigned, and they both have the aliasing exception rules. (This makes `std::byte` pretty hard to sell - `unsigned char*` was already idiomatic for bytes on any platform where `CHAR_BIT` is 8.)

Comment: @ArthurTacca IMO it's not limited to 8-bit `char`s -- a `char` is always one byte i.e. the same size as a `std::byte`. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bytes-review

Answer (score 4):

What is the motivation for `std::byte`?

Quoting from the [original paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r0.pdf);

> Many programs require byte-oriented access to memory. Today, such programs must use either the `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char` types for this purpose. However, these types perform a “triple duty”. Not only are they used for byte addressing, but also as arithmetic types, and as character types. This multiplicity of roles opens the door for programmer error - such as accidentally performing arithmetic on memory that should be treated as a byte value - and confusion for both programmers and tools.

In essence, `std::byte` is there to "replace" the use of `char`-types when required to deal with raw memory as bytes, it would be safe to assert that this is applicable when used by-value, by-reference, pointers and in containers.

> `std::byte` does not have the same connotations as a char; it's about raw memory, not characters

Correct, so `std::byte` should be preferred over `char`-types when dealing with bytes in memory (as in, an array of bytes). Some lower level protocol data manipulation immediately comes to mind.

> What is a good rule of thumb, for the days of `std::byte`, regarding when to prefer it over `void *` and when it's the other way around?

I would argue that similar guides apply now as they did previously. When dealing with raw blocks of memory, where the byte addressability is required, `char *` etc. would have been preferred over `void *`, I think the same logic applies now, but prefer `byte *` over `char *`. A `char *` is better for a character sequences.

If the desire is to pass around a pointer opaquely, the `void *` probably still best fits the problem. `void *` essentially means "point to anything", but the anything is still something, we are just not saying what yet.

Further, the types [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (and `intptr_t`) would probably factor in as alternatives, depending of course on the desired application.

> ... I mostly mean new code where you get to choose all the types.

New code generally has very limited use of `void *` outside of compatibility (where you don't get to choose the type). If you need byte based processing then favour `byte *`.

Comment: Ah, but you're ignoring an important point. The thing is, in some cases `void *` was used not because it was objectively appropriate, but because it was better/not as bad as `char*` or `unsighed char*`. So the availability of `std::byte*` changes the balance. So in principle it should not be the case that the same guidelines apply for `std::byte *` as for `char *`.

Comment: _but because it was better/not as bad as_ I'm not sure I agree, compatibility or vendor specific rules aside. An example would be needed. `char*` and `void*` had different use cases and special treatment, most evident in the rules around `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`. I'm not sure what in the text about `byte` fundamentally changes this.

Comment: *An example would be needed* - well, take some facility for allocating raw, untyped memory. Should it return `void *`'s or `byte *`s?

Comment: It returns a `void *` because that memory is for an object. One will be created there - we just don't know what yet. If the memory should be addressed as an array of bytes, the cast to `char*` or `byte*` would be done.

Comment: There's no guarantee the allocation is for an object. Maybe you're just reserving memory space to protect against leaks. The code _using_ a low-level memory allocator may be constructing an object there.

Comment: _There's no guarantee the allocation is for an object_, ok, but the general use case for an allocation and creation functions is to create an object, well formed. If the allocation has the limited use to reserve empty memory, then any return type would do - it won't be used.

Comment: In your conclusion at the end of your post, you seem to be missing the point that `std::byte` __is basically a restricted type of `unsigned char`__. We presumably want to avoid
"_...accidentally performing arithmetic on memory that should be treated as a byte value_"
Unless you want to define bitwise math on your data, you should not just use `std::byte*` to replace `void*`.
`std::byte*` is not meant to just replace `void*` anymore than `char*` will just replace any occurrence of `void*` at your preference

Answer (score 3):

First, `void *` still makes sense when you have to use a C library function or generally speaking to use any other `extern "C"` compatible function.

Next a `std::byte` array still allows individual access to any of its elements. Said differently this is legal:

```
std::byte *arr = ...;
arr[i] = std::byte{0x2a};
```

It makes sense if you want to be able to allow that low level access, for example if you want to manually copy all or parts of the array.

On the other hand, `void *` is really an *opaque* pointer, in the sense that you will have to cast it (to a `char` or `byte`) before being able to access its individual elements.

So my opinion is that `std::byte` should be used as soon as you want to be able to address elements of an array or move a pointer, and `void *` still makes sense to denote an opaque zone that will only be passed (hard to actually process a `void *`) as a whole.

But real use case for `void *` should become more and more unusual in modern C++ at least at high level, because those opaque zones should normally be hidden in higher level classes coming with methods to process them. So IMHO `void *` should in the end be limited to C (and older C++ versions) compatibiliy, and low level code (such as allocating code).

Comment: So, would you say that a C++ memory allocating facility should produce  `byte*`s rather than `void*`s?

Comment: @einpoklum: No I just say that a high level C++ facility should produce objects (as `new` does). Of course at a low level, `void *` would be approriate because the allocated memory is seen as a whole. But few C++ programmers write low level allocating code... Anyway, I've edited my answer with that.

Comment: *Is* that legal?  It would require an implicit conversion from `int` to `std::byte`, which I don't see.  So wouldn't you have to write `arr[i] = std::byte{0x2a};` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oups! You are perfectly right, and I've edited my post. My compiler is not C++17 compatible so I could not test it before posting. Thank you for the fix...

Answer (score 0):

`std::byte` is not just about ["raw memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610772/), it is byte-addressable raw memory *with bitwise operations defined for it*.

You should not use `std::byte` to just blindly replace `void*`.  `void*` retains its use. `void*` means to the handling code "this is a block of data but I don't know *what this data is*, nor do I know *how to operate on it*.

Use `std::byte` when you need byte address of the memory block *and only bitwise operations defined* for operating on that data.

`std::byte` does **not** have regular basic math operations defined, such as `operator+`, `operator-` or `operator*`. That's right, the following code is illegal:

```
std::byte a{0b11},b{0b11000};
std::byte c = a+b; // fails, operator+ not defined for std::byte
```

In other words, use `void*` when it is not *the handling codes business the contents*.

## std::byte Example

Like I said above, all you can do on a `std::byte` are the bitwise operations like `|`, `&` and `~`. An example of the use of `std::byte` follows, note you need a C++17 compiler to compile this example, there is one [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) but you must select C++17 from the dropdown at the top right

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

void print(const byte& b)
{
  bitset<8> p( to_integer<int>( b ) );
  cout << p << endl;
}

int main()
{
  byte a{0b11},b{0b11000};
  byte c=a|b;
  //byte d = a+b; // fails
  print(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This just expands on my question, where I already mentioned a `byte` is not like a `char`. You're not actually answering the question.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica It does now, in the very first line. Actually you don't need to ask this question, the answer is already in how you asked it. You know not to use `char*` over `void*` for data that is not characters, and you should know not to use `std::byte*` over `void*` for data that you don't want the [facilities `std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) provides

Comment: What do you believe one should use for the result of, say, `malloc()`?

Comment: A pointer of the type the memory is for -- UNLESS you need to keep the internal access of this memory hidden to some code -- then `void*`. `void*` is like a type of `private` for the internals of the raw memory.